# Does anyone have a good recommendation for a book which teaches sharding?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Does anyone have a good recommendation for a book which teaches **db sharding** (from scratch at best)

I have read like 40 different websites talking about sharding.

I'm not saying online sites/blogs are lousy, they are good titbits. However, I need the main meal not just a it of useful info here and there. Basically, I have an idea (I guess) of how to implement sharding but, since it's a terribly complicated concept, I believe there is much, much, much more to it that can be studied on.

Comment: if you read 40 different website, then you must learnt `sharding`..isn't it??

Comment: yep. i've learnt that *sharding* is not something which we can learn from simply reading 40+ different online tutorials / blog posts. it's way more complicated than that.

Comment: This is off topic here; I'm going to shoot you over to [dba.SE] because they're going to know more about it than your average programmer.

Comment: @Uraha, would you share some of useful links and let me know is that really so complicated as u r saying..Thanks

Comment: DB Sharding == Horizontal Partitioning ... Correct?

Answer (score 5):

A great place to start is the book [High Performance MySQL : Optimizations, Backups, Replication and More](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596101716). Chapter 9 (pages 409 - 456) of the book is entitled "Scaling and High Availability"

There are the subheadings

- Scaling MySQL
- Planning for Scability
- Buying Time Before Scaling
- Scaling Up
- Scaling Out

  - Functional partitioning
  - Data Sharding
  - Choosing a partitioning key
  - Multiple partitioning keys
  - Querying across shards
  - Allocating data, shards and node
  - Arranging shards on node
  - Fixed allocation
  - Mixing Dynamic and Fixed Allocation
  - Explicit Allocation
  - Rebalancing Shards
  - Generating globally unique IDS
  - Tools for sharding
- Scaling Back
- Scaling by Cluster
- Load Balancing
- Connecting Directly

and two dozen other subheadings

Comment: thank you. I've finished that chapter. But I still do not think it provides deep enough info into this subject. Is there an entire book dedicated to this subject rather than a book that dedicates only one chapter on this subject?